# Calculate difference in values between 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, subquery

Hope some SQL expert can advice and provide the most efficient t-sql code to retrieve the following results.

I've 2 tables.

Orders and Journal.

Orders will have a OrderID,CustomerID, GrandTotal and Paid column.
Journal will have OrderID and Credit field.

For each Orders row, there may be more than 1 related rows in the Journal.
I want to retrieve results of OrderID and Outstanding (GrandTotal - Sum(Credit)) Where CustomerID=@CustomerID and Paid=false

eg. In Orders table
OrderID: 1, CustomerID:1, GrandTotal: 1000, paid=false
OrderID: 2, CustomerID:1, GrandTotal: 200, paid=false
OrderID: 3, CustomerID:1, GrandTotal: 500, paid=false
OrderID: 4, CustomerID:2, GrandTotal: 500, paid=true

In Journal table
OrderID: 1, Credit: 100
OrderID: 1, Credit: 200
OrderID: 2, Credit: 100
OrderID: 4, Credit: 500

So result would be
OrderID: 1, Outstanding: 700 (1000-Sum(100+200)
OrderID: 2, GrandTotal: 100 (200-Sum(100))
OrderID: 3, GrandTotal: 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select orderid, (grandtotal-credits)
from orders
left join (select sum(credit) as credits from journal group by orderid) as credits on credits.orderid=jornal.orderid
where orders.paid=false and customerid=@Customerid
```

I did left join in case not all of your customers have credits.